# Trying to use text from a file and sort it

Tags: c#

I am running into a brick wall every time I try to do this. What I cannot figure out is why my code will not pull my information from a text file and sort it. Everything that I have done looks to be good. 
I get 3 errors in line 76, 86 and 103. They state 'yourChoicesItems' does not exist in the current context and yourChoicesPrices' does nto exist in teh current context.
But I do not see what is wrong.
When I put in the date such as: public string[] yourChoicesItems = {etc....} it works.
Why will this not work?

my text file is: (there is a space before each line)

BlueberryBagels 0.75
 HashBrowns 2.50
 BottledSoda 1.50
 Coffee 0.90
 Donut 1.50
 FrenchFries 1.50
 BlueberryMuffins 0.85
 LiteYogurt 0.75
 HotChocolate 1.75
 OnionSoup 3.00
 PecanPie 2.75
 PurpleYam 2.75
 StrawberryBagels 0.80
 Toast 2.00
 VanillaIceCream 2.75
 IcedTea 1.00

```
using System.IO;

namespace testce
{
    public partial class MainScreen : Form
    {
        static void InsertSort(IComparable[] array)
        {
            int i, j;
            for (i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                IComparable value = array[i];
                j = i - 1;
                while ((j >= 0) && (array[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
                {
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    j--;
                }
                array[j + 1] = value;
            }
        }
        int count = 0;
        double totalTax = 0;
        double totalSale = 0;

        public MainScreen()
        {
            FileStream fStream = new FileStream("menu.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(fStream);
            string inValue;
            string[] values;
            double price;
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            while (!inFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                inValue = inFile.ReadLine();
                lines.Add(inValue);
                values = (inValue.Split(" ".ToCharArray()));
                price = double.Parse(values[2]);
                InsertSort(values);
            }
            inFile.Close();
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeControls();

            for (int index = 0; index < listBox.SelectedIndices.Count; index++)
            {
                subTotal = subTotal + yourChoicesPrices[listBox.SelectedIndices[index]];
            }

            for (int index = 0; index < listBox.SelectedIndices.Count; index++)
            {
                textBox.AppendText(yourChoicesItems[listBox.SelectedIndices[index]] + "\n");
            }
            Text = "Thank you for using Food Systems Inc.";
            this.listBox.DataSource = yourChoicesItems;
            this.btnOne.Text = "Place Order";
            this.label.Text = "Menu Selection";
            this.labell.Text = "Order Information";
        }

        public System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnOne;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general guideline, this is way too much code for the given problem. Try to keep it readable.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel... Sorting an array is a solved problem, there are many ways to do it in .NET without writing the sort algorithm yourself. For instance you can just use `Array.Sort`.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - this has all the marks of a learning exercise and that is usually about reinventing something.

Comment: I do not see where you are declaring your `YourChoicesItems` and `YourChoicesPrices`

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have edited my code to shorten it, this should be the only code that is needed to review it.

Comment: @MarkHall what to I declare them to? Such as if I had string YourChoicesItems = ??? To what?

Comment: It will be two array (double and string).

Comment: I am not sure, it looks like it should be a either an `array` or a `List<string>` you will also need to populate them with your data. You can not use a variable with out it being declared somewhere, the compiler will ask the same question that you just did.

Comment: `string[] yourChoicesItems;` and `double[] yourChoicesPrices;` though I probably would use decimal instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is Java like and it's not too much correct in c# so i have made some modification:

```
class FoodData
{
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

First of all we are using a oop language so it's better use a class with two properties instead of a single `String`

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists("menu.txt"))
            return;
        string[] values;
        double price;
        List<FoodData> lines = new List<FoodData>();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("menu.txt"))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() > -1)
            {
                values = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                FoodData tmp = new FoodData();
                tmp.FoodName = values[0];
                tmp.Price = Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);
                lines.Add(tmp);
            }
        }
```

This is the common method with in c# the file is read. the using construct permitt to avoid the closing of sr because after this the pointer is immediately disposed.

Now you must implement the IComparable interface if you want use the `Sort` method of a list

```
lass FoodData_SortByPriceByAscendingOrder : IComparer<FoodData>
{
    public int Compare(FoodData x, FoodData y)
    {
        if (x.Price > y.Price) return 1;
        else if (x.Price < y.Price) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
class FoodData_SortByPriceByDescendingOrder : IComparer<FoodData>
{
    public int Compare(FoodData x, FoodData y)
    {
        if (x.Price < y.Price) return 1;
        else if (x.Price > y.Price) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
class FoodData_SortByName : IComparer<FoodData>
{
    public int Compare(FoodData x, FoodData y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x.FoodName, y.FoodName);
    }
}
```

These 3 class inherits the IComparer interface(that receive a FoodData list). It's not to difficult to understand but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3.aspx) you can find the references and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42839/Sorting-Lists-using-IComparable-and-IComparer-Inte) an example

After the classes are done you call these from main like that:

```
FoodData_SortByPriceByAscendingOrder fAsc = new FoodData_SortByPriceByAscendingOrder();
        lines.Sort(fAsc);
        FoodData_SortByPriceByDescendingOrder fDesc = new FoodData_SortByPriceByDescendingOrder();
        lines.Sort(fDesc);
        FoodData_SortByName fByName = new FoodData_SortByName();
        lines.Sort(fByName);
```

Answer (score 0):

`yourChoicesPrices` and `yourChoicesItems` aren't declared in the given code. That's why you get this error. You need to declare them.